# Show only 50 characters in meteorjs and bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I am using Meteorjs and bootstrap 3 for my application. I am quite new to both of these. What I am doing is I am fetching some objects from database and rendering them in a Table . but the problem is if the object text is long it increases the table Row size which affect all the template structure. I can do this by hiding the overflow but that is not a right way to do this. I am doing it like this

```
{{#each questions}}
    <tr>
        <td>
<a href="#" data-id="{{_id}}" class="edit"> {{question_text}}</a>
         </td>
    </tr>
{{/each}}


Template.questions.questions = function () {
    questions= Meteor.questions.find({topic_id: Session.get("currentTopicId")});
    return questions
}
```

I want to show only first 50 characters of the question in the TD cell following by a few dots. How can I do this In meteorjs. Do i need to split the text before rendering that ? or Tell me how can I split the question_text in template or is there any inbuilt method which shows only first 50 characters of the text.

#### My next query is when I print or do console.log(questions) it shows me many fields like collections, queries, and some other things where queries, results, docs each containes the object questions. How can I get these questions objects from the response object. means i want to iterate a loop over these questions objects. How can i do that.

In simple i want to iterate the loop over the retrieved objects.

### Can someone Post a complete Example using handlebarsjs.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with helpers.

```
 Handlebars.registerHelper('trimString', function(passedString) {
      return new Handlebars.SafeString(passedString.substring(0,50))
   });

{{trimstring question_text}}
```

Comment: Thanx Ugur Toprakdeviren. Today is my second day with meteorjs. Let me try with the stuff you told me. I need to learn handlebars first of all

Comment: Can you lease explain this method some more. means how can i pass the value to this helper function and then return a list of appropriate values

Comment: If i am trying to do like u pass {{trimstring question_text}} its throwing an error

Comment: It was server crashing error. now i have change the things. I am trying to do it like this. 
`Template.questions.questions = function () {
    console.log("this functions has been claalled")
    return Questions.find({topic_id: Session.get("currentTopicId")}).map(function(question) {
        return question.question_text.substr(0,50);
    });
};` on console its is showing me the text. but not returning anything to template.

Comment: The error was my trimString function was not getting called. now it isworking fine

Answer (score 2):

In the world of CSS3 trimming text in JS is no longer the case. I would encourage you to use CSS3 for that. Benefits?

- Trimmed text after hovering is displayed in the full format in a hint,
- Dynamic trimming that is related to element width (td cell in this case),
- More flexibility

```
.trimmed { 
    overflow: hidden; /* needed to make text-overflow work */
    text-overflow: ellipsis; /* adds '...' */
    width: 9em; /* can be fixed of flexible like % */
    white-space: nowrap; /* do not wrap text if it not fit in an element */
}
```

Comment: Thanx Jagi, But u used meteor helpers method bcz that seems much better and efficient than hiding the over flow

Comment: It depends on which efficiency you talk, server or client? CSS is for presentation layer and trimming text is a presentation issue. But of course you can trim text server side if you wish :).

Comment: yes, you are right Jagi, thank you, The way you told using that all the data will be there but hidden. but here, I am getting  a sub string of only 50 characters and sending that to the table.